# Node.js render LaTeX code

Tags: node.js, latex, mustache

I'm trying to execute the following code in Node.js:

```
var docdata = {paper_size: "a4paper", file: inFileName}
var output = Mustache.render("\documentclass[twoside]{article}\usepackage{pdfpages}\usepackage[{{paper_size}}]{geometry}\begin{document}\includepdf[pages=-]{{{file}}}\end{document}\batchmode", docdata);
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
var output = Mustache.render("\documentclass[twoside]\{article\}\usepackage\{
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
  at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:902:3
```

How should I escape the LaTeX string to render it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all the backslashes with two backslashes `\\`, like

`"\\documentclass[twoside]{article}\\usepackage{pdfpages}\\usepackage[{{paper_size}}]{geometry}\\begin{document}\\includepdf[pages=-]{{{file}}}\\end{document}\\batchmode"`

Backslashes in string literals have special meaning, allowing you to escape characters like `"`, or add special characters, like newline `\n`. But this means that if you want an actual backslash, you have to escape it (with another backslash), like `\\`.